# How do I implement six initial conditions for a system of two coupled second order differential equations?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations, scientific-computing, numerical-analysis

I am new to coding. Basic information about my problem is: r1 and r2 are two variables; u1 = dr1/dt, u2 = dr2/dt, and du1/dt = d^2r1/dt^2, du2/dt = d^2r2/dt^2. In Matlab code: r(1) implies r1, r(2) -> u1, r(3) -> r2, r(4) -> u2. rdot(2) is the expression for du1/dt and rdot(4) is the expression for du2/dt.
Ideally I should need just 4 initial conditions: r1(0), u1(0), r2(0), u2(0), which are 10d-6, 0, 5d-6, 0. But in my case du1/dt has dependence on du2/dt and vice versa. See last term of T1_1 and T2_1. And an ideal IC for both du1/dt and du2/dt is 0. But how do I implement this in my code?

My code is here.

---

```
function rdot = f(t, r)

P_stat = 1.01325d5;
P_v = 2.3388d3;
mu = 1.002d-3;
sigma = 72.8d-3;
c_s = 1481d0;
poly_exp = 1.4d0;
rho = 998.2071d0;
f_s = 20d3;
P_s = 1.01325d5;
r1_eq = 10d-6;
r2_eq = 4d-6;
d = 1d-3;


rdot(1) = r(2);
P1_bw = ( (P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(1))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) - (2.d0*sigma/r(1)) - (4.d0*mu*r(2)/r(1));
P1_ext = P_s*sin(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(1)/c_s)));
T2_1 = ((2.d0*r(3)*(r(4)^2.d0)) + ((r(3)^2.d0)*rdot(4)))/d;
T2_4 = (1.d0 - (r(2)/c_s))*r(1);
T2_5 = 1.5d0*(1.d0 - (r(2)/(3.d0*c_s)))*(r(2)^2.d0);
T2_6 = (1.d0 + (r(2)/c_s))*(P1_bw - P_stat + P_v - P1_ext)/rho;
T2_8 = ( (-3.d0*poly_exp*r(2)*(P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(1))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) + (2.d0*sigma*r(2)/r(1)) - (4.d0*mu*(- ((r(2)^2.d0)/r(1)))) )/r(1);
T2_9 = 2.d0*pi*f_s*P_s*(cos(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(1)/c_s))))*(1.d0 + (r(2)/c_s) );
T2_7 = (r(1)/(rho*c_s))*(T2_8 - T2_9);
rdot(2) =  (T2_6 + T2_7 - T2_1 - T2_5)/(T2_4 + (4.d0*mu/(rho*c_s)));


rdot(3) = r(4);
P2_bw = ( (P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(3))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) - (2.d0*sigma/r(3)) - (4.d0*mu*r(4)/r(3));
P2_ext = P_s*sin(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(3)/c_s)));
T1_1 = ((2.d0*r(1)*(r(2)^2.d0)) + ((r(1)^2.d0)*rdot(2)))/d;
T1_4 = (1.d0 - (r(4)/c_s))*r(3);
T1_5 = 1.5d0*(1.d0 - (r(4)/(3.d0*c_s)))*(r(4)^2.d0);
T1_6 = (1.d0 + (r(4)/c_s))*(P2_bw - P_stat + P_v - P2_ext)/rho;
T1_8 = ( (-3.d0*poly_exp*r(4)*(P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(3))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) + (2.d0*sigma*r(4)/r(3)) - (4.d0*mu*(- ((r(4)^2.d0)/r(3)))) )/r(3);
T1_9 = 2.d0*pi*f_s*P_s*(cos(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(3)/c_s))))*(1.d0 + (r(4)/c_s) );
T1_7 = (r(3)/(rho*c_s))*(T1_8 - T1_9);
rdot(4) =  (T1_6 + T1_7 - T1_1 - T1_5)/(T1_4 + (4.d0*mu/(rho*c_s)));

rdot = rdot';
```

---

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
time_range = [0 3000d-6];
initial_conditions = [10d-6 0.d0 5d-6 0.d0];
[t, r] = ode45('bubble', time_range, initial_conditions);
plot(t, r(:, 1), t, r(:, 3));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For each degree of an ODE you'll need one initial condition. This is due to the amount of functions you are calculating. In your case you got a system of second order ODE's, which after being solved will provide a total of four functions: `r(1), r(2), r(3), r(4)`

Why do we even need initial conditions? Imagine you have a simple derivative:`y'= y`
We know that the function `y = exp(x) * C` solves this problem, but we need to adjust `C` in order to get "The one Solution". On the other hand side it makes no sense to give `y'` an initial condition, as it is fully defined, once `y` is defined. It doesn't matter whether the "foreign" variable appears in the form of a derivative or as a linear factor. It is independent from the amount of IC's.

I hope I could clarify it a bit. From my point of view your program should work that way, but I haven't had the chance to try it out.

Comment: Thanks but the two ODEs are coupled. y1'' = f(y1(0), y1'(0), y2''(0)) is here instead of the regular y1'' = f(y1(0), y1'(0)) which most of us are used to.

Comment: You mean `y(t)=C*exp(t)` as the solution of `y'=y`. The additive constant is in the logarithm, `ln|y(t)|=t+c`.

Comment: @Vikash You can proof with e.g. Picard-Lindelhof that a ODE just needs n initial conditions for n-degrees. More than that define a not-well-posed Problem, which basically is not consistent and/or stable. Maybe I am wrong but I think it does not play a role whether you have a second derivative of your coupled variable inside the ODE or not.

Comment: @Pablo, I know what you said. But notice, that the additional IC required here is not from the same variable, it is from another variable.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you all so much for helping me fix this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially the situation that

```
rdot(2) = a2 + b2*rdot(4)
rdot(4) = a4 + b4*rdot(2)
```

where `a2,b2,a4,b4` contain all the other terms in your expressions.

This is a linear system that you have to solve to get the correct values to return. You can use a linear solver of Matlab or do in this simple 2-dimensional case do it by hand,

```
rdot(2) = a2 + b2*(a4 + b4*rdot(2))  ==>  rdot(2) = (a2 + b2*a4) / (1 - b2*b4)
rdot(4) = a4 + b4*(a2 + b2*rdot(4))  ==>  rdot(2) = (a4 + b4*a2) / (1 - b2*b4)
```

---

To apply this you need to split

```
T1_1  as T1_1a + T1_1b*rdot(4),
```

you can compute `T1_1a` and `T1_1b` from the given constant and state variables. Then where you have in the end

```
 rdot(2)=(other + coeff*T1_1)/denom
```

you have to split into

```
 a2 =(other + coeff*T1_1a) / denom    and 
 b2 =         coeff*T1_1b  / denom
```

and do the same to the second part to get `a4,b4` and then apply the solution formulas above.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem, by introducing two new variables with initial conditions but then they are updated as the code runs. The new code is here with two variables: r2ddot and r1ddot;

```
function rdot = f(t, r)

P_stat = 1.01325d5;
P_v = 2.3388d3;
mu = 1.002d-3;
sigma = 72.8d-3;
c_s = 1481d0;
poly_exp = 1.4d0;
rho = 998.2071d0;
f_s = 20d3;
P_s = 1.01325d5;
r1_eq = 4d-6;
r2_eq = 5d-6;
d = 50*(r1_eq + r2_eq);

r2ddot = 0;
r1ddot = 0;

rdot(1) = r(2);
P2_bw = ( (P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r2_eq))*((r2_eq/r(3))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) - (2.d0*sigma/r(3)) - (4.d0*mu*r(4)/r(3));
P2_ext = P_s*sin(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(3)/c_s)));
T1_1 = ((2.d0*r(1)*(r(2)^2.d0)) + ((r(1)^2.d0)*r1ddot))/d;
T1_4 = (1.d0 - (r(4)/c_s))*r(3);
T1_5 = 1.5d0*(1.d0 - (r(4)/(3.d0*c_s)))*(r(4)^2.d0);
T1_6 = (1.d0 + (r(4)/c_s))*(P2_bw - P_stat + P_v - P2_ext)/rho;
T1_8 = ( (-3.d0*poly_exp*r(4)*(P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r2_eq))*((r2_eq/r(3))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) + (2.d0*sigma*r(4)/r(3)) - (4.d0*mu*(- ((r(4)^2.d0)/r(3)))) )/r(3);
T1_9 = 2.d0*pi*f_s*P_s*(cos(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(3)/c_s))))*(1.d0 + (r(4)/c_s) );
T1_7 = (r(3)/(rho*c_s))*(T1_8 - T1_9);
rdot(2) =  (T1_6 + T1_7 - T1_1 - T1_5)/(T1_4 + (4.d0*mu/(rho*c_s))) ;
r2ddot = rdot(2);

rdot(3) = r(4);
P1_bw = ( (P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(1))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) - (2.d0*sigma/r(1)) - (4.d0*mu*r(2)/r(1));
P1_ext = P_s*sin(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(1)/c_s)));
T2_1 = ((2.d0*r(3)*(r(4)^2.d0)) + ((r(3)^2.d0)*r2ddot))/d;
T2_4 = (1.d0 - (r(2)/c_s))*r(1);
T2_5 = 1.5d0*(1.d0 - (r(2)/(3.d0*c_s)))*(r(2)^2.d0);
T2_6 = (1.d0 + (r(2)/c_s))*(P1_bw - P_stat + P_v - P1_ext)/rho;
T2_8 = ( (-3.d0*poly_exp*r(2)*(P_stat - P_v + (2.d0*sigma/r1_eq))*((r1_eq/r(1))^(3.d0*poly_exp)) ) + (2.d0*sigma*r(2)/r(1)) - (4.d0*mu*(- ((r(2)^2.d0)/r(1)))) )/r(1);
T2_9 = 2.d0*pi*f_s*P_s*(cos(2.d0*pi*f_s*(t + (r(1)/c_s))))*(1.d0 + (r(2)/c_s) );
T2_7 = (r(1)/(rho*c_s))*(T2_8 - T2_9);
rdot(4) =  (T2_6 + T2_7 - T2_1 - T2_5)/(T2_4 + (4.d0*mu/(rho*c_s)));
r1ddot = rdot(4);
rdot = rdot';


clc;
clear all;
close all;
time_range = [0 1d-3];
initial_conditions = [4d-6 0.d0 5d-6 0.d0];
[t, r] = ode45('bubble', time_range, initial_conditions);
plot(t, r(:, 1), t, r(:, 3));
```

But I am not able to get the desired result. Actually I am trying to reproduce the results from the attached paper, see equation 7. [enter link description here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.56.2924)

[image]

The second set of equations can be obtained by interchanging indices 1 and 2.

Important note: There is a typo in the last term of equation 7 in Mettin's paper, that can be verified by using check on the dimensions of the various term. The correct last term can be seen from another paper https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.83.066313
See last term in eq.(1) below. Ignore the other extra terms in the equation. Important point is that the equation is of second order in Rj and the equation has a second order term in Ri at the end. And This is what I have tried to code.
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The cited equations should be moved to the question as they are supplemental information. I do not see where you get the `rdot` terms on the right side from, as `rdot(2)` is `\ddot R_1` and `rdot(4)` is `\ddot R_2` and the second derivatives occur just once per equation and can easily be isolated.

Comment: Also, are you mixing up the variables? p2w in (8) should be computed using R2, you are computing a similar term using R1. And how did you come to use a double derivative in the last term of (7) when the cited formula only has first derivatives?

Comment: Lutzl, You could have a point there. Let em check that and get back to you. It seems I may have been doing the same error in all my codes if that is true. I need to check my derivations. Will be back in an hour or so.

Comment: Lutzl, There is probably a typo in the last term of Equation 7. One could check it from dimensional analysis too. I checked some other papers and I find my coding equations to be correct. To support my claim, I have added another picture above and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense as that then combines to `d/dt(R1²*dR1/dt)=d²/dt²(R1³)/3`. See my answer as that became relevant again.

Comment: By the way you were correct on mixing variables for P1 and P2 for both bw and ext. After having done that correction, now I am getting some result. Not sure if that is correct though. But do you think that my two parameters introduction into the program is not okay?

Comment: No, you are using `r1ddot=0` instead of the correct value. And as `r2ddot=rdot(2)` depends on it, it also has the wrong value. It is also not very sound to take the values from a previous evaluation, but as these variables are not defined as global, that is not happening.

Comment: The zero values are used only in the first run and then they are updated as the code loops over and over again. Lutzl, can you do skype chat for few minutes?

Comment: So, may be retain only one of the two additional parameters with zero as its IC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182500/discussion-between-vikash-and-lutzl).